# How to get form element seen in DOM and not in source code?

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, marketo

We are using the marketo form on one of our Drupal installation and I am trying to add a on click event when the button is clicked. But when I view the source I cannot see the from element . I can see it on the DOM inspector however.

This is what I see on the view source.

```
<form class="marketo-form-wrapper"
  data-formid="####"
  data-campaign="######"
  data-file="####"
 id="####">
```

The inspect element screenshot is attached.[image]

No matter what I do I cannot call the click function when the submit button is clicked.
I could do upto this point

```
$('.marketo-form-wrapper').click(function (e)  {          
 console.log('clicked');});
```

I dont want this function to be called when user clicks on the form wrapper. I want it to be called when the actual button is clicked.

If I do this nothing shows up.

`$('.marketo-form-wrapper .mktoButtonRow:button').click(function (e)  {

 console.log('clicked');});`

Comment: Delegate event to handle dynamic element: `$('.marketo-form-wrapper').on('click', ' .mktoButtonRow:button', function (e)  {...});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the delegate selector.

```
$('.marketo-form-wrapper').on("click",".mktoButton",function(){
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

This will apply a click handler to any element with the .mktoButton class, inside the .marketo-form-wrapper class, added after the DOM has loaded.  Which is the case in your question.

Comment: Oh my god. I cannot thank you enough. This works perfectly fine .

Comment: I don't think that's how that works. The delegate event handler is applying an event listener on `.marketo-form-wrapper` and then essentially filtering that down if the target is `.mktoButton` its not actually applying a listener to `.mktoButton`

Comment: I may not be explaining it correctly, and you may be correct.  But this is indeed what the OP needed.